How to implement method correctly for a struct with AsRef<str> generic?
I have a following type:
pub enum AppError<S: AsRef<str>> {
    ScenarioError(S, Option<S>),
    SystemError(S),
}

impl<S: AsRef<str>> AppError<S> {
    pub fn user_not_exists() -> Self {
        AppError::ScenarioError("User not exists", None)
    }
}

I have a following compiler error for a first ScenarioError argument:
mismatched types
expected type parameter `S`
        found reference `&'static str`

How to describe this type to accept a &'static str argument too?
